# number of query values and destination fields are not the same

Tags: vb6

I think something is lacking or i had used the wrong syntax. can you please help me trace my error?

Private Sub AddScholarbtn_Click()

```
If txtSchoolID = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Input ID")
ElseIf txtSSName = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Input Surname")
ElseIf txtSGName = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Input Given Name")
ElseIf txtSMName = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Input Middle Name")
ElseIf txtAddress = "" Then
    MsgBox "Null"
ElseIf txtBirthPlace = "" Then
    MsgBox "Null"
ElseIf ComboMonth = "" Then
    MsgBox "Select Month"
ElseIf ComboDay = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Select Day")
ElseIf ComboYear = "" Then
    MsgBox "Select Year"
ElseIf comboGender = "" Then
    MsgBox "Select Gender"
ElseIf ComboCivilStatus = "" Then
    MsgBox "Select Status"
ElseIf txtAge = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Input Age")
ElseIf txtContactInfo = "" Then
    MsgBox "Null"
ElseIf txtEmail = "" Then
    MsgBox "Null"
ElseIf txtGuardian = "" Then
    MsgBox "Null"
ElseIf txtGContact = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Null")
ElseIf txtYOA = "" Then
    MsgBox "Null"
ElseIf comboProgram = "" Then
    MsgBox "Null"

Else

    Dim ans
    ans = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to Save this Scholar?", vbYesNo, "Save")
    If ans = vbYes Then


          ''''''''''''In this line where the yellow color/error occurs


    DBConnect.Execute "INSERT INTO tblScholarProfile VALUES(" + txtSchoolID + ",'" + txtSSName + "','" + txtSGName + "','" + txtSMName + "' ," & _
                    " '" + txtAddress + "','" + txtBirthPlace + "','" + ComboMonth + "'," + ComboDay + "," + ComboYear + "," & _
                    " '" + comboGender + "','" + ComboCivilStatus + "'," + txtAge + "," + txtContactInfo + ",'" + txtEmail + "','" + txtGuardian + "'," + txtGContact + "," + txtYOA + ",'" + comboProgram + "')"
```

I dont really get where I got this wrong.

```
        MsgBox "You have successfully save a new Scholar"
    Else
        MsgBox "Save unsuccesful!"
    End If
    Unload Me
    MainMenuForm.Show

End If
```

End Sub

Please help. Im a newbie :(

Answer (score 1):

You have more or less comma delimited items in your `VALUES` string than there are fields in the `tblScholarProfile` table.

- Look at the parsed SQL string and ensure each value matches with a field in the table
- If there is an identity column make sure you are not including it in the `VALUES` list
- Ensure you are not missing any `'` string delimiters

Additionally a `'` in one of the text boxes will cause an error and is an SQL Injection vulnerability, at the very least you should `replace()` any `'` characters in the submitted text with `''` (2 x `'`) to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed one upper comma here `txtSchoolID + ",'" + txtSSName` check the values and you will find